# Wordpress content on non-WP site residing on a remote domain -- how to display posts?

Tags: rss, xml

I have a website (non-wordpress) with a sidebar that I want to display the "latest 3 posts" from my wordpress blog that resides on a different server. I would like to also style the 3 posts using CSS/HTML.

What is the recommended method for displaying a "latest posts" feed on a non-wordpress website that has severe restrictions such as no editing of the wordpress theme, no uploading of plugins, no database modifications, no public internet access (internal network), etc?

I can grab an RSS feed from the blog and try to parse and display it on my non-wordpress website, but I am unsure what or how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can grab an RSS feed by going to /feed/, adding /feed/ to the end of any WordPress archive or page will give you an RSS feed.

You can then grab this remotely and display the first 3 items in your sidebar.

However, your sidebar is inside a non-WordPress site. So the styling, html, how to grab an RSS feed, etc, are all off topic here, as they're non-WordPress questions